# How to derive the Matsubara correlator?

Tags: greens-functions, correlation-functions, thermal-field-theory

So the Matsubara correlator for either bosons or fermions is given by
$$G(i \omega_n) = 1/(i \omega_n  - \epsilon_k ), \quad (1)$$

with $\epsilon_k$ being the single particle energy and $\omega_n$ being the Matsubara sum. Although this expression looks simple, to derive this seems to be quite tough, specifically, following the derivation in [Schmalian's lecture notes](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/ss2018_tkm2/TKM2_revised.pdf).

I am stuck with proving that the expression in (251)
$$ G(i \omega_n) = \frac{1}{Z} \sum_{l,m } \frac{(\exp(- \beta E_l )  + \eta \exp(- \beta E_m ) ) \langle l | A | m  \rangle \langle m | B | l\rangle }{ i \omega_n  + E_l - E_m } $$
leads to (1), where $A$ or $B$ correspond to the bosonic and fermionic creation operators because
$G(i\omega_n, k ) = \langle c_k  , c^{\dagger}_k\rangle$. So I get that because $A$ and $B$ create and annihilate, $E_m - E_l = \epsilon_k$, so that at least the fraction matches up with (1). But how do you prove that the numerator cancels out with the factor $1/Z$?